# Azure DevOps Proxy On Premise Proxy Server - Multiple Collections?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a large on-premise Azure DevOps installation that consists of many Projects contained within multiple Collections.

I am setting up a new Proxy Server through the Azure DevOps Server Administration Console Wizard and do not seem to be able to have it service all of the existing Collections, instead forcing me to choose only one.

We have other existing Proxy Servers that service multiple Collections, but these were set up many years ago and have remained mostly untouched apart from annual upgrades.

We are currently running Azure DevOps 2020 Update 1.1, so I was wondering if it is still possible to create a Proxy Server that services multiple Collections?

Comment: hi , could you share with us the latest status of your issue?

Comment: +1 -- We've noticed the exact same thing. Moreover, what does Microsoft recommend to people who needs to work on several collections when you can only configure 1 proxy in your Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

During the installation, we found that our proxy server could only be connected by one collection, the same as your scenario.

[image]

So I suppose that you could raise a [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOpsServerTFS/suggest?) for multiple collections demand.